# dequeue is strange in the iteration, but isn't outside the iteration

Tags: c, queue

It's quite strange that I put the dequeue operation in the iteration to print the character in order, but it failed and only print the first two characters, but when I use this dequeue operation outside the iteration, it's all right!

I define dequeue as follows:

```
char *C_dequeue(struct COMMON_QUEUE *q) {
  if (C_get_queue_length(q)==0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Linked queue is empty!!!");
    return NULL;
  }
  struct QUEUE_NODE *p;
  p = malloc(sizeof(struct QUEUE_NODE));
  if (p==NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  p = q->q_node;

  char *temp;
  temp = p->next->string;
  p = p->next;
  q->q_node->next = p->next;
  free(p);
  p->next = NULL;
  p->string = NULL;

  return temp;
}
```

and use it in the main.c file:

```
struct COMMON_QUEUE *test10;

test10 = C_init_queue();

C_enqueue(test10, "Someone ");
C_enqueue(test10, "like ");
C_enqueue(test10, "you!");

printf("length: %d\n", C_get_queue_length(test10));
int j;

/* it prints the first two characters */
for (j = 0; j <= C_get_queue_length(test10)+1; ++j) {
  printf("[%d %s]", j, C_dequeue(test10));
}
printf("\n");

/* it prints all the characers */
C_dequeue(test10);
C_dequeue(test10);
C_dequeue(test10);

C_destroy_queue(test10);
```

I think I could have made some silly mistake!!!

Comment: One silly mistake I see immediately is you're allocating *anything* during a dequeue operation, and leaking memory in the process. When you do this: `p = malloc(sizeof(struct QUEUE_NODE));` and then immediately after this: `p = q->q_node`, what do you think happened to that allocation? hint: `int a=5; a=6;` Where did the `5` go? *This Isn't Java*.

Comment: How is COMMON_QUEUE defined? if it contains `char string[..]` it's not sufficient to store the address (`temp = p->next->string`)

Comment: @WhozCraig, but, I allocate space for p, and copy the `q->q_node` to p, I think it's ok I just do the copy job, and I searched that ANSI support this way, but instead, am I going to use `memcpy`?

Comment: Your code overwrites the allocation you made. Perhaps I didn't say it clearly. **C Is Not Java**. And the answer to my hint question? Where did the 5 go ? `p` is a *pointer*. It is a *variable* that *holds* a memory address. Assigning a new memory address to `p` (like the one stored in the pointer `q->q_node`), *overwrites* the value there previously, just like having `int a=5;` then running `a=6`. The value is overwritten, the previous value lost. You need a good tutorial/book on using pointers memory addresses (they're *not* the same), and dynamic memory management.

Comment: @WhozCraig, so there's no need to `malloc` memory address to `p`. By the way, due to your explanation, do you have some good tutorials/books on using pointers memory addresses to recommend?

Comment: There are plenty online. Google "Pointers C Tutorial".

Comment: @WhozCraig, thank you, I'm reading now!!!

Answer (score 1):

C_get_queue_length(test10)+1 is evaluated each iteration of the loop.
As the queue gets shorter, at some point it becomes less than j.

I suspect this happens after the second iteration, thereby ending the loop.

Although the '<=' and the '+1' look like you have tried to fix the problem some other way.

```
int len = C_get_queue_length(test10) ;
for ( j = 0 ; j < len ; j++) { ...}
```

is what you want

Comment: `j<=C_get_queue_length(test10)+1` is just for testing and only in this way does it print the correct answer.

Comment: Well that's what I thought, but I'd suggest that's a bad habit to get into, because once it works you might be tempted to leave it in. And now you have 2 bugs that cancel each other out. Better to have 0 bugs.

Comment: Oh of course I won't leave it in because I just want to figure out where the bug lies, I love to code rigorously! :P